# SocialLib error creating TwitterConnector

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, twitter-oauth

Here is the code, what's relevant. I have keys, secret and callback variables defined. I'm using these library versions: SocialLibBeta2_2.jar, signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar, signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar, scribe-0.6.7-SNAPSHOT.jar.

```
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.SocialNetworkHelper;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.TwitterConnector;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.exceptions.NotAuthentifiedException;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.model.twitter.TwitterUser;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.scribe.oauth.Token;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;

public void SendTweet()
{
TwitterConnector twitter = SocialNetworkHelper.createTwitterConnector(CONS_KEY, CONS_SEC, CALLBACK);

try {
        twitter.requestAuthorization(this);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        twitter.authorize(this);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Token at = twitter.getAccessToken();
    String token = at.getToken(); 
    String secret = at.getSecret();

    Token myAccessToken = new Token(token, secret);
    twitter.authentify(myAccessToken);

    try {
        twitter.tweet("Test tweet");
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotAuthentifiedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Here is the error:

```
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.TwitterConnector.requestAuthorization(TwitterConnector.java:287)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.sirva.mymc.JournalActivity.SendTweet(JournalActivity.java:247)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.sirva.mymc.JournalActivity$1$1.onClick(JournalActivity.java:135)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-17 19:05:18.958: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The TwitterConnector function that's blowing up looks like this:

```
public void requestAuthorization(Context ctx) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException 
{
  String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, callback);
  ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
}

protected TwitterConnector(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callback){
  this(consumerKey, consumerSecret, callback, "");
}

protected TwitterConnector(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callback, String twitPicKey){
  this.authentified = false;
  this.reader = new TwitterReader();
  this.twitPicKey = twitPicKey;
  this.callback = callback;
  httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
  httpOauthprovider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(TWITTER_REQUEST, TWITTER_ACCESS, AUTHORIZE);

}
```

Here is a quick test app to make sure that no other library is having issues with it

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.SocialNetworkHelper;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.TwitterConnector;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.exceptions.NotAuthentifiedException;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.model.twitter.TwitterUser;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.scribe.oauth.Token;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String CONS_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String CONS_SEC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String CALLBACK = "http://xxxx.com";

    TwitterConnector twitter = SocialNetworkHelper.createTwitterConnector(CONS_KEY, CONS_SEC, CALLBACK);

    try {
        twitter.requestAuthorization(TestActivity.this);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        twitter.authorize(this);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Token at = twitter.getAccessToken();
    String token = at.getToken(); 
    String secret = at.getSecret();

    Token myAccessToken = new Token(token, secret);
    twitter.authentify(myAccessToken);

    try {
        twitter.tweet("Test tweet");
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotAuthentifiedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

}
```

I get the same error when running this. TestActivity.this is a valid context, i have access to the method requestAuthorization but it says NoSuchMethodError again. Libraries included in the test project: commons-codec-1.6.jar, scribe-0.6.6.jar (tried 0.6.7 too), signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar, signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar, signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar, SocialLibBeta2_2.jar.

Here's the manifest as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have this problem before because i missed lib but i see now you include them in project , so what's the problem ?

Comment: I have tried all 3 libraries from oauth-signpost and scribe. I have tried both the versions of signpost 1.2.1.1 and 1.2.1.2 as well as scribe 0.6.6 and 0.6.7-SNAPSHOT. I'm still getting this error. I'm using apache common's codec 1.6 and yet i'm still getting the NoSuchMethodError on the retrieveRequestToken. I'm going to try another clean project and just call this directly to see if it's another library causing a conflict.

Comment: test project failed. added the activity/manifest and library inclusion for the test project. I'm stumped on this one...

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss lib you should include in project that's why you are getting this error you should download those 3 libs from [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list) and download [this](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe/downloads) lib also or you will get another Exception again

Comment: I downloaded scribe 6.7, should i be using scribe-0.6.6-javadoc.jar? Also from signpost, i'm using the latest 2 but not signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar... i didn't see the need for jetty. Not quite sure why i'm getting an error on requestAuthorization in the TwitterConnector. I'll add the jetty file from signpost and drop/add the libraries back again. If i get the error again i'll get a screen shot showing the libraries are in fact there.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to just go with Scribe instead. SocialLib was giving me too many problems.